# JAXB @XmlElementWrapper to use @XmlRootElement of wrapped object

Tags: java, jaxb

How do you tell JAXB to use the `@XmlRootElement` annotation of data wrapped in a `@XmlElementWrapper` collection?  I know you can use `@XmlElement` to name each, individual item but I'm curious to see if there is a way to just have it automatically pick it up for me.

For example:

```
@XmlElementWrapper (name = "records")
private List<?> records;
```

Will Produce:

```
<records>
    <records ...>
        <child_with_proper_name ... />
</records>
```

But let's say the `List` contains objects of:

```
@XmlRootElement (name = "my_element")
```

I want to generate this:

```
<records>
    <my_element>
        <child_with_proper_name />
    </my_element>
</records>
```

Without doing this:

```
@XmlElementWrapper (name = "records")
@XmlElement (name = "my_element")
private List<?> records;
```

It **seems** like it should know to pick up the `@XmlRootElement` name, but it does not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
@XmlElementWrapper (name = "records")
@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
private List<?> records;
```

**Note**

On an unmarshal operation any elements encountered that do not correpond to an `@XmlRootElement` annotation will be kept as DOM nodes.

Comment: Perfect.  Also, I wrote a quick unit test to do a covered a matched `@XmlRootElement` and an unmatched one and it still works just fine, but like you said, it's just a basic DOM node.